# Show using the properties of event space (sigma-algebra) that (1/2,2/3) is also an event.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ and we know that sets $[0, x]$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ are events. Show using the properties of event space (sigma-algebra) that $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right)$ is also an event.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

1. $(a,b]=[0,b]\setminus [0,a]$
2. $(a,b)=\bigcup_n (a,b_n]$ where $b_n$ increases and converges to $b$.